# Find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of laplacian on $(0,1)^2$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Considering the laplacian operator, using separation of variables, find its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Nope, this is the question:
Consider the operator −∆ on the domain (0,1)2 with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.
a) Using separation of variables, find its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Cla What did you got by separating the variables of the Laplacian?

Comment: An eigenfunction and eigenvalue of the Laplacian operator would be a function $f$ and scalar $\lambda$ such that $-\Delta f = \lambda f$, so find functions and scalars that satisfy that relationship. As you've specified you are working with the Laplacian in two dimensions, try working with **polar coordinates** and see where that gets you.